# Python conflict with keyword "from" in telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I would like to print user information in Python script using python-telegram-bot referring to [this](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#user) page

But when I type

`print update.message.from`

keyword `.from` is recognized as internal reserved keyword and I get invalid syntax error.

How can I solve?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume the API returns json? So you should be able to load the response and then access its properties like update['message']['from'] or something like that.

Comment: While you cannot specify invalid name attributes directly in the source code you *can* do: `getattr(update.message, 'from')`

Comment: @eatmeimadanish It's about the `from`.

Comment: @eatmeimadanish What do you mean with "reconstruct"?

Comment: update.message..__getattribute__('from').id

Comment: @KellyBundy because you aren't always in control of the creation of the object... otherwise why are they asking the question....

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas A traceback? For code that never ran? (because it's a syntax error)

Comment: @KellyBundy but still it should show something more then only `from ^^^^`

Comment: @furas Hmm... I find it clear the way it is. They even already went further than that, identifying the issue as the word being a keyword. The error message doesn't say that. They figured that out themselves and told us.

Comment: @KellyBundy full error can show in which file is real problem - so I can even open source code to see if there is some extra information or some method for solution. Sometimes it shows what version on Python has this problem and which version of module has problem (so if I have different version then I check if update can resolve problem). And often beginners skip some important infromation so I prefer to see full error.

Comment: @furas Hmm, it has been a keyword since at least Python 1.4 from 1996 (the oldest doc [available here](https://www.python.org/doc/versions/)), so I doubt it would ever not have been a problem. Telegram is not even half as old.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained in the [python-telegram-bot code](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/61fe438a8be3d0c1780a43f2fae044dedbcbf54e/telegram/choseninlineresult.py#L30) and [documentation](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.choseninlineresult.html) itself:

> - In Python `from` is a reserved word, use `from_user` instead.

So: `print update.message.from_user`.

Answer (score -2):

Use `getattr`.

```
x = getattr(update.message, 'from').id
```

It's not the name of the key that is a problem, but the attempt to access it using attribute syntax.